# How to split a list of lists

Tags: python

So I want to split a list of lists.

the code is

```
myList = [['Sam has an apple,5,May 5'],['Amy has a pie,6,Mar 3'],['Yoo has a Football, 5 ,April 3']]
```

I tried use this:

```
for i in mylist:
  i.split(",")
```

But it keeps give me error message

I want to get:

`["Amy has a pie" , "6" , "Mar 3"]` THis kinds of format

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Try `i[0].split(",")`: each `i` is a one-item list.

Comment: What is `i`? Are you sure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you do it. I used an inline for loop to iterate through each item and split them by comma.

```
myList = [item[0].split(",") for item in myList]
print(myList)
```

**OR** You can enumerate to iterate through the list normally, renaming items as you go:

```
for index, item in enumerate(myList):
    myList[index] = myList[index][0].split(",")
print(myList)
```

**OR** You can create a new list as you iterate through with the improved value:

```
newList = []
for item in myList:
    newList.append(item[0].split(","))
print(newList)
```

Comment: I suggest you to answer using their approach, I mean with a normal for loop. Perhaps he also wants to perform another statements that could be hard to understand using a comprehension list. IMHO

Comment: I added a couple variations, he can choose.

Answer (score 2):

Split each string in sublist :)

```
new = []
for l in myList:
    new.append([x.split(',') for x in l])

print new
```

Comment: I still want list of lists

Comment: I got[[['Sam has an apple,5,May 5']],[['Amy has a pie,6,Mar 3']],[['Yoo has a Football, 5 ,April 3']]]

Comment: change append to +=

`new+=[x.split(',') for x in l]`

Answer (score 1):

It's because it's a list of lists. Your code is trying to split the sub-list, not a string. Simply:

```
for i in mylist:
    i[0].split(",")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be:

```
list(map(lambda x: x[0].split(","), myList))
```

Comment: Note that this is less performant than a list comp because of the cost of the function call (lambda).